# Add attribute to embed tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, object, embed, attributes, wmode

I have the following embed tag:

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="505" src="url_to_video" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
```

I have about five of theses on a page, and I'd like to add the attribute wmode="opaque" to all of them. However, I tried to do it like this and it didnt' work:

```
$j("embed").attr('wmode','opaque');
```

Is there another way I can dynamically set the attribute wmode="opaque" ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ened up using a regular expression instead of jquery to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Look at SWFObject

http://www.web-site-scripts.com/flash-charts/online-manual/index.html?fcp_sample_of_usage_swfobject.html

Comment: What am I doing wrong here?

$j("embed").each(function(){
        
var so = new SWFObject($j(this).attr("src"), "flash-video", $j(this).attr("width"), $j(this).attr("height"), "8", "#000000");

so.addParam("wmode", "opaque");
so.write("embed");
    
});

Comment: are you using a different version of jquery?  I just noticed the $j